# Moving bottom border up for inline text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the bottom border up so it's closer to the text when you hover.
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/s8ctga2o/

I've tried using pseudos but they don't work as intended. Only every second item gets a bottom border and the first paragraph of text, only the last line does and not all of it.

```
.project-link span a {
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
}

.project-link span a:hover:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:1px;
border-bottom:solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what effect you want to achieve? I don't quite get it by viewing your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Passerby i think he/she want show border-bottom of all a tag at once when hover

Comment: @Passerby I just want to move the border when you hover upwards like 5px or something.

Comment: wont be possible i guess, because its already touching the the characters like 'y'  and 'g'

Comment: @atinder Updated OP with pic. The font I'm using has more spacing for some reason than the one in the fiddle.

Comment: @user2252219 `::after` wouldn't help in this case, due to the rendering nature of `display:inline` and `display:inline-block`: https://jsfiddle.net/s8ctga2o/1/ . I think Zwander's answer is by far the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear. I've taken it as:
You want an underline on the text at all times and when you hover, the underline should move upwards.

I have done this below:

```css
.project-link {
    line-height:30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.project-link:hover {
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="project_wrap">
    <div class="project_miniwrap"> <a class="project-link" href="#" id="toggle">Graduated with a background in Biological Sciences and pursuing a Masters of Industrial Design at Pratt Institute in Brooklyn, NY. I strongly believe in thoughtful design. Here are a couple of my projects over the years. </a>
 <a class="project-link" href="#modal1" id="one" >Modurra Shelving </a>  <a class="project-link" href="#modal2" id="two" >Kami Bicycle Helmet </a>  <a class="project-link" href="#modal3" id="three" >Revamping Language Learning </a>  <a class="project-link" href="#modal4" id="four">Sports Innovation Challenge </a>  <a class="project-link" href="#modal5" id="five" >Lights Out </a>  <a class="project-link" href="#modal6" id="six" >Maru Personal Speaker Design </a>  <a class="project-link" href="#modal7" id="seven">A Few Casual Projects </a> 
    </div>
```

I've cut out all the other styling and left only the hover.

The important part is the switching between margin-bottom and padding-bottom. Padding will move the border but margin will not. Thus you can swap them over to cause the border to move upwards.

If you want to prevent the spazzing out when you hover below, wrap your links in a div and give the div `class="project-link"`. Give the div `padding-bottom:Xpx`. Change the css to modify the child elements:

```css
.project-link > a{
    line-height:30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.project-link:hover  > a{
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
}
.project-link{
    display:inline;
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project_wrap">
    <div class="project_miniwrap">  
        <div class="project-link">
            <a  href="#" id="toggle">Graduated with a background in Biological Sciences and pursuing a Masters of Industrial Design at Pratt Institute in Brooklyn, NY. I strongly believe in thoughtful design. Here are a couple of my projects over the years. </a>
        </div>
        <div class="project-link"><a class="project-link" href="#modal1" id="one" >Link a </a> </div>
        <div class="project-link"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal2" id="two" >Link B </a> </div> 
        <div class="project-link"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal2" id="two" >Link C </a> </div> 
        <div class="project-link"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal2" id="two" >Link D </a> </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be misleading people. What I mean is that if you look at the picture I added to OP. The line when you hover is too far from the text. I want to move it up closer.

Comment: Yea that's what the css I provided does :)